# What is the best way for user to use a filter

Tags: usability, filter

Good day, I would like to get some feedback on our decision.

We have a system in which our user can create, store and manage metadata (we call it an `object card`) of various intellectual property objects (music, video, etc.), as well as, in particular, establish a hierarchical relationship of objects between various objects.

To search for objects, a special filter is used in which our user can specify keywords, as well as indicate where exactly these words are to be searched (in object title, in object authors, in object copyright holders, etc., or generally everywhere – in all fields).

You can watch the process of searching and choosing a relationship between various objects on the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BnYm1fOeIw
In this example, our user searches for the object `We will rock you` in all fields of the object card, and then indicates that it searches only in object title.
In the process of entering characters, the system immediately displays the found objects.

Please rate, in your opinion, convenience of this interface in terms of finding a suitable object for establishing a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

That whole interface seems overly complicated. Even with the video, I'm not exactly clear what's going on. So my rating is "low".

Based on your description, it seems like a search/filter of content will be extremely important for most interactions with the system. With that in mind, I'd develope an overarching search pattern that works across the board.

A reduction process often works well in cases like this. If you create an `autocomplete` style structure that shows context it would be much easier for your users to interact with.

[image]